# ngModel default value setting doesnt receive info from model

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a form and I want to set some default values to be shown inside it. I have tried the following code:

```
 <h3>ِStart Time</h3>
    <div class="row" >
      <div class="col">
        <label for="startTime">Hour(s) </label>
        <input type="number" [ngModel]="defaultSTime" class="form-control" name="StartTimeHour" value="card.startTime.getHours" id="startTime" min="0" max="23">
     </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label for="startTime">Minute(s) </label>
            <input type="number" [ngModel]= "defaultSMinute" class="form-control" name="StartTimeMin" value="card.startTime.getMinutes" id="startTime" min="0"max="59"> <!--input type can be changed accordingly-->
      </div>
    </div>


  defaultSTime = 'card.startTime.getHours' ;
  defaultSMinute = 'card.startTime.getMinutes';
```

this is supposed to work but it only shows me the empty box. where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue but from your definition of defaultSTime and defaultSMinute, they are strings while your inputs are defined as number type.

If you're trying to get a number from card object card.startTime.getHours,  change your definition to:

```
defaultSTime = card.startTime.getHours;
defaultSMinute = card.startTime.getMinutes;
```

Comment: but this gives me an error, when I write this.card. .... I dont get anything on display either

Answer (score 0):

This will help you :

[[image]

Also, to make it two way binding, keep banana-in-a-box for ngModel, i.e :

```
[(ngModel)]= "defaultSMinute"
```

There, is not much clarity in your comments - how you are constructing Card object, but i believe you missed following:

```
getHours() ; // these are functions of date not properties
```

[image]

Comment: the form of start time is date: new Date(2019, 6, 1,13,30) , I also made it a 2 way binding but it doesnt work. plus when I use this. ... It gives out a compile error

Comment: can you add snippet, where and how are you defining this date

Comment: `someting = [  new CardModel('5',new Duration(1, 0), new LessonModel('#6291E1', 'Math'), 'just the first part', true,true,new Date(2019, 6, 2,13,30),new Date(2019, 6, 2),false,false)]`